# How can I block an audio (mic) control in spring

Tags: spring, jsp, audio, getusermedia

I programmed a simple service that have two buttons.
If first btn is clicked, browser asks to user "Can you permit the mic in this browser?".
Another btn serves as the opposite.

This is a first btn's function code.

```
function fnc_start(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});}
```

Finally, I want a code that blocks mic.

Comment: I completed this problem!

Answer (score 0):

This code is a solution!

```
var mdstrm = new MediaStream();

function fnc_start(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}).then(mediaStream => {
      mdstrm = mediaStream;
    })
}


function fnc_end(){
    console.log("Yalu~~~end");

    const tracks = mdstrm.getTracks()
    tracks[0].stop()

    console.log("It's real!!"); 
}
```